# Тихая авторизация встроенного приложения PowerApps в ASP.NET Core

Tags: c#, active-directory, oauth2, .net

Всем привет.
Имею приложение PowerApps, которое необходимо встроить в страницу приложения на ASP.NET Core. Встраивается легко, фреймом, но, вопрос в том, что мне необходимо реализовать работу приложения так, чтобы оно не требовало авторизации  в AAD через всплывающее окно, а просто начинало работать. Иными словами, нужно чтобы этот «фрейм» всегда считал, что мы уже авторизованы. Много ломал голову, перерыл пол интернета, ничего дельного. Пришёл к тому, что похоже, само PowerApp-приложение как то должно «тихо» авторизовываться, но, не уверен.

Может быть, кто то сталкивался?
Спасибо, заранее!

Comment: А что не получилось? А что получилось?

Comment: @4per, Я предполагаю, что это все добро можно было бы просто отключить, но, лицензия организации не позволяет этого сделать(

Comment: @4per,  Получилось отдельно отправить запрос к oauth, используя ROPC-flow. Токен-то я получил, но вот погоды мне он особо никакой не играет, у меня же iframe по идее?... Нашёл проект-пример с MSDN, который умеет «авторизовывать» пользователей, причём «тихо». Но, он все равно, при первом запуске попросил ввести учетные данные и предоставить разрешения для приложения, а после авторизации, iframe так же, требует дополнительной. В Local Storage, в данном случае, видел сообщения вида “Cannot complete frame silent authentication"